# GMAP Control ".NET is not a member of 'GMapControl'"

Tags: vb.net, google-maps, maps

I am getting solution errors when trying to run my application using the GmapControl package. Deleted the lines with errors does not seem to affect the application in any way but allows me to run the application, shortly after a while of debugging the lines reappear in the designer.vb file and the errors return.

```vb
Me.GMap.Bearing = 0!
Me.GMap.CanDragMap = True
Me.GMap.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill
Me.GMap.EmptyTileColor = System.Drawing.Color.Navy
Me.GMap.GrayScaleMode = False
Me.GMap.HelperLineOption = GMap.NET.WindowsForms.HelperLineOptions.DontShow 'Error Line
Me.GMap.LevelsKeepInMemory = 5
Me.GMap.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(3, 3)
Me.GMap.MarkersEnabled = True
Me.GMap.MaxZoom = 2
Me.GMap.MinZoom = 2
Me.GMap.MouseWheelZoomEnabled = True
Me.GMap.MouseWheelZoomType = GMap.NET.MouseWheelZoomType.MousePositionAndCenter 'Error Line
Me.GMap.Name = "GMap"
Me.GMap.NegativeMode = False
Me.GMap.PolygonsEnabled = True
Me.GMap.RetryLoadTile = 0
Me.GMap.RoutesEnabled = True
Me.GMap.ScaleMode = GMap.NET.WindowsForms.ScaleModes.[Integer] 'Error Line
Me.GMap.SelectedAreaFillColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(CType(CType(33, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(65, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(105, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(225, Byte), Integer))
Me.GMap.ShowTileGridLines = False
Me.GMap.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(658, 455)
Me.GMap.TabIndex = 1
Me.GMap.Zoom = 0R
```

Comment: It's good that you formatted your code but code snippets with big wads of leading whitespace are harder to read. If you had not removed the whitespace from the first line only (why do petiole do that?) then you could have used the site editor to remove it all. That said, you can hold down the Alt key when selecting an arbitrary block of text in VS, so there's no need to copy any irrelevant whitespace in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is a name clash. `GMap` is a namespace and that is what `.NET` is a member of but you have added a `GMapControl` with the name `GMap` as well, so that is what the compiler is interpreting that name as. Notice how those lines all have `Me.GMap` on the left? The ones with `GMap` on the right are being interpreted as referring to that same `GMapControl` rather than the appropriate namespace. If you change the name of the control then the issue will go away.

You may need to either delete those lines first or edit them by hand afterwards though, because the rename may change the name of the namespace as well.

This is an example of why it's important to put some thought into your control and other names. If you use names that are descriptive in your specific scenario then name clashes are less likely.